# SSRS audit log of subscription changes

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to view the parameter details each time a particular subscription was ran in SSRS 2008 R2?

I can see in the reportServer DB the executionLog table, but this does not record the actual Subscription that ran (we can have dozens of subscriptions per report). Also I cannot join the subscription table to the executionLog table as the only key is the ReportID.

I can find the specific subscription in the Subscription table using the description, but I need to find an audit log of changes that were made to each subscription over a period of time eg - the DataSource was changed or a paramter was changed from A to B. I know that these changes can only be done with a certain security level and each time the change needs to be saved - but can this info be pulled for specific subscriptions?

Thanks